# trying to understand scoping problem scenarios and best resolutions for scss in react apps

Tags: reactjs, sass

I want to make sure I understand the scoping issue when using scss with React.  Is the following scenario an accurate example?:

- framework.scss has a .submit-button css class definition with background-color:grey
- user-admin.scss has a .submit-button css class definition with background-color:green
- user-admin.tsx imports both of those scss files.

So does the scoping issue in this scenario refer to duplicate class names for submit-button which have different values for the background-color attribute?

Would this scoping issue be resolved by simply ensuring that components import more general scss files before more specific scss files?

What are the most commonly used and broadly accepted strategies for managing scoping issues with scss in React apps?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity

Answer (score 0):

You can handle the scoping issue by using [CSS modules](https://www.makeuseof.com/react-components-css-modules-style/).

Import your stylesheet:

`import style from 'framework.module.scss'`

Use classes like this:

`<div className={style.submit-button}></div>`.

Or this for more than one class:

```
className={`${style.foo} ${style.bar}`}
```